# Co-dependent TextField in SwiftUI (two way data binding)

Tags: swift, swiftui

Attempting to write a temperature converter using SwiftUI.

I want that by typing a temperature in the Celsius input the Fahrenheit reflects the converted temperature immediately and vice-versa.

[image: UI]

I attempted to use `onChange` but that creates a loop: `Celsius -> onChange(Celsius) -> update Fahrenheit -> onChange(Fahrenheit) -> update Celsius`, which results in typing `1` in Celsius and the input becoming `1.000` making it impossible to type two digits.

The following code is almost what I want, it uses `onEditingChange`. The issue is that it requires the focus on the TextField to be lost in order to update the other number.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var temperatureCelsius: String = "0"
    @State private var temperatureFahrenheit: String = "32"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Text("Temperature Converter")
                .font(.system(size: 36))
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    TextField("     ",
                              text: $temperatureCelsius,
                              onEditingChanged: { newValue in
                                temperatureFahrenheit = String(convertToFahrenheit(celsiusTemperature: Float(temperatureCelsius) ?? 0.0))
                              }
                        )
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .fixedSize()
                    Text("ºC")
                    
                }
                Image(systemName: "arrow.left.arrow.right")
                    .imageScale(.large)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                HStack {
                    TextField("     ",
                              text: $temperatureFahrenheit,
                              onEditingChanged: { newValue in
                                temperatureCelsius = String(convertToCelsius(fahrenheitTemperature: Float(temperatureFahrenheit) ?? 0.0))
                              }
                        )
                        .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .fixedSize()
                        
                    Text("ºF")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Ideally there would be a way to know when the user changed the value vs the code changed the value. This way I could make this two way data binding work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making your own `Binding` that wrap the `@State`s works.

```
@State var celsiusText = "0"
@State var fahrenheitText = "32"
```

```
TextField("     ",
          text: Binding(get: {
                celsiusText
            }, set: {
                celsiusText = $0
                
                let temperatureC = Measurement(value: (try? FloatingPointParseStrategy(format: .number).parse($0)) ?? 0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
                fahrenheitText = temperatureC.converted(to: .fahrenheit).value.formatted()
            }))
```

```
TextField("     ",
          text: Binding(get: {
                fahrenheitText
            }, set: {
                fahrenheitText = $0
                let temperatureF = Measurement(value: (try? FloatingPointParseStrategy(format: .number).parse($0)) ?? 0, unit: UnitTemperature.fahrenheit)
                celsiusText = temperatureF.converted(to: .celsius).value.formatted()
            })
    )
```

Note that I have used a `Measurement` here to do the temperature conversion, and I have used a locale-sensitive way of parsing and formatting the numbers, because the default `description` formatting just outputs way too many decimal places :)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for! Appreciated it ‍♂️